# Input boxes over image

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML, CSS. Can anyone help me with setting the input boxes over the image?

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="img" style="position:relative;" >
    <img src="C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\n3.jpg" max-width:100% height:auto>
        <div style="position:absolute;">
    <pre>

    Login:<input name="login" placeholder="enter your mail id here" type="email">       Password:<input name="password" placeholder="password"  type="password">
    </pre>
    </div>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

This code first shows image and then input boxes under it. 
Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: <div id="img" style="position:relative; background-image: url(C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\n3.jpg)'>

Comment: @Lain If you think that's an answer why not post as such?

Comment: @ToothlessRebel: Too less information.. is it an image for the textbox, for the div, for a part of it.. who knows.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear how this is supposed to look but something like this

```css
#img {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
#img div {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#img div label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="img" style="position:relative;">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/">
  <div>
    <form>
      <label for="login">Email</label>
      <input name="login" placeholder="enter your mail id here" type="email" />
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input name="password" placeholder="password" type="password" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the css 'top: 0px' to the second div.

New code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="img" style="position:relative;" >
        <img src="C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\n3.jpg" style="max-width:100% height:auto">
        <div style="position:absolute; top: 0px;">
            <pre>

                Login:<input name="login" placeholder="enter your mail id here" type="email">       Password:<input name="password" placeholder="password"  type="password">
            </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid inline styles and create a better structure. Adjust the value of top to your requirement.

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
}

#img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="img">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" />
  <div class="content">
    <pre>
    Login:<input name="login" placeholder="enter your mail id here" type="email">       Password:<input name="password" placeholder="password"  type="password">
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is to use the image in the background of the parent div of your inputs.

`Login:<input name="login" placeholder="enter your mail id here" type="email">       Password:<input name="password" placeholder="password"  type="password">
</pre>
</div>`